# Tentando aplicar lambda no dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando aplicar essa função no dataset:

```py
 number_outliers = (df2 < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df2 > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))

        df2.apply(((lambda x:df2[~((df2 < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df2 > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)))])),axis=1, broadcast=True, raw=True, reduce=True ,args=number_outliers )
        return df2
```

Onde o number_outilers é um parametro para identificar os outliers e a funçao do lambda é para remover , não sei onde estou errando , alguem teria alguma sugestão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer é fazer um *subset* do banco. Nesse caso não precisa definir uma função. O comando correto para encontrar o número *outliers* de uma variável `var` seria:

```
import numpy as np

Q1 = np.percentile(df2['var'], 25, interpolation='midpoint')
Q3 = np.percentile(df2['var'], 75, interpolation='midpoint')
IQR = Q3-Q1
number_outliers = df2[ (df2['var'] < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df2['var'] > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))]['var'].size
```

Exmplo replicável:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var': [-400, 1, 2, 3, 400],
                    'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

Q1 = np.percentile(df2['var'], 25, interpolation='midpoint')
Q3 = np.percentile(df2['var'], 75, interpolation='midpoint')
IQR = Q3-Q1
number_outliers = df2[ (df2['var'] < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df2['var'] > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))]['var'].size

print(number_outliers)
```